# How strict is the "bad question ban" filter?

Tags: support, post-ban

I was going to type up a question today on Stack Overflow, and it warned me that I'd submitted too many "bad" questions recently and was in danger of being temporarily banned from asking questions. I checked my history, and of the ~30 questions I've asked, only two have ever received negative points (the most being -2 points).

Additionally, I have zero deleted questions as far as I can tell. Some of my questions have thousands of views, and while none of them get MASSIVE upvotes, responses have always been pretty positive.

What's going on?

Comment: I had got only 5 upvoted questions and 5 downvoted questions, as well as about 18 0-voted questions. I got question-banned until I got a single upvote which lifted me out of it (and then I posted a question which got 5 upvotes). But that was at a equal good-bad question ratio!
Considering you only have one downvoted post and over 10 upvoted posts, then you should be nowhere near the ban, and if I went by what I have experienced I would say that you would need at least 5 downvoted posts to even reach a warning, let alone be banned.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You received the warning automatically because of your 2 most-recent questions. Your most-recent question was closed, the one before that was downvoted to -2. It looks like that is enough to give you a reminder to post good, on-topic questions.

It is *just* a warning, and you can ignore it if you feel your questions *on the whole* meet the quality standards.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sorting by date, so I didn't realize that was the case. Two questions is pretty quick, but I guess it *is* just a warning. Thanks, friend!

Comment: Wow, two bad questions and you get a warning for a ban?

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica: more of a reminder that the ban exists? *Oi, if you keep heading in that direction you'll fall of the cliff into the shark-infested waters! Be careful!*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I understand.  I'm just surprised that it only takes two questions!  I don't know if I would have made it through the new user process back when I started...  X'D

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica: I am not privy to the details; I just found that the two most recent posts could be seen as 'not well received'. It may also have looked at the last 3, with the preceding question scoring 0, rather than have a positive score. *Overall* the most recent 3 questions where then not well received either.

Comment: IIRC it's also based on reputation, isn't it?  IE, if I asked a couple of bad questions, it would be less likely to warn/ban me than Dan, who's very low in reputation still?

Comment: @Joe: probably. Since the details are deliberately not made public to prevent gaming, I cannot be sure. But it'd make sense.